# Windows Form Analog Clock integrate to Web Part Moss 2007

Tags: windows, forms, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have a windows form analog clock and I need to create a web part (moss 2007).

my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;


namespace ClockWebPart 
{
    public class ClockWebPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {

        Form form = new Form();

        ///  Constructor
        public ClockWebPart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// Initialization here
        private void ClockDesign_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // read the embeded resource
                Assembly asmImage = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                Stream streamImage = asmImage.GetManifestResourceStream("ClockWebPart.clock.bmp");
                Bitmap bmpBackground = new Bitmap(streamImage);
                SetFormBackgroundImage(bmpBackground);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Resource wasn't found!");
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        ///  Set the form background
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bmpImage"></param>
        private void SetFormBackgroundImage(Bitmap bmpImage)
        {
            Color clrPixel = bmpImage.GetPixel(0, 0);
            bmpImage.MakeTransparent(clrPixel);
            form.BackgroundImage = bmpImage;
            // Set the form size from image size
            form.Size = bmpImage.Size;
        }

        /// Override the paint event
        //protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        //{
          //  base.OnLoad(e);
        //}


        protected void OnPreRender(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set the origin to center of the form
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(80.0F, 80.0F);

            // Save translated graphics state; So origin will remain at center of form when restore
            GraphicsState transState = e.Graphics.Save();

            // Capture a copy of current time for consistent
            DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;

            // rotation starts from new center of the form
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(dtNow.Second * 6.0F - 90.0F);
            // Anti-alias only affect the next shape
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            // draw the second hand at new center of the form
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Silver), -1, -1, 55, 2);

            //// Restore graphics state to translated state and fill second hand
            e.Graphics.Restore(transState);

            // minus 90 degree because start at x-axis
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(dtNow.Minute * 6.0F - 90.0F);
            // Anti-alias only affect the next shape
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Silver), -1, -1, 45, 3);

            //// Restore graphics state to translated state and fill minute hand
            //gHands.Restore(transState);
            // Reset transformation matrix to identity and fill rectangle.
            e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
            // Set the origin to center of the form
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(80.0F, 80.0F);

            // minus 90 degree because start at x-axis; Minute affects hour hand too
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(dtNow.Hour * 30.0F - 90.0F + dtNow.Minute * 0.5F);
            // Anti-alias only affect the next shape
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Silver), -1, -1, 35, 4);
        }


        /// Force the form to repaint for every tick

        private void tmrRotate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Force to redraw
            //this.Invalidate();
            form.Refresh();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>


        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(ClockWebPart));
            this.niMainMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);
            this.cmsAllMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
            this.tsmiAbout = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.tsmiSeparator = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
            this.tsmiExit = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.tmrRotate = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.cmsAllMenu.SuspendLayout();
            form.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // niMainMenu
            // 
            this.niMainMenu.ContextMenuStrip = this.cmsAllMenu;
            this.niMainMenu.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("niMainMenu.Icon")));
            this.niMainMenu.Text = "Time flies!";
            this.niMainMenu.Visible = true;
            // 
            // cmsAllMenu
            // 
            this.cmsAllMenu.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.tsmiAbout,
            this.tsmiSeparator,
            this.tsmiExit});
            this.cmsAllMenu.Name = "cmsAllMenu";
            this.cmsAllMenu.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(108, 54);
            // 
            // tsmiAbout
            // 
            this.tsmiAbout.Name = "tsmiAbout";
            this.tsmiAbout.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 22);
            this.tsmiAbout.Text = "About";
            //this.tsmiAbout.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tsmiAbout_Click);
            // 
            // tsmiSeparator
            // 
            this.tsmiSeparator.Name = "tsmiSeparator";
            this.tsmiSeparator.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 6);
            // 
            // tsmiExit
            // 
            this.tsmiExit.Name = "tsmiExit";
            this.tsmiExit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 22);
            this.tsmiExit.Text = "Exit";
            //this.tsmiExit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tsmiExit_Click);
            // 
            // tmrRotate
            // 
            this.tmrRotate.Enabled = true;
            this.tmrRotate.Interval = 1000;
            this.tmrRotate.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.tmrRotate_Tick);
            // 
            // frmIrregular
            // 
            form.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            form.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            form.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(160, 160);
            form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            form.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            form.Name = "frmIrregular";
            form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            form.Text = "Time flies";
            form.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            form.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ClockDesign_Load);
            //this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.frmIrregular_MouseDown);
            //this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.frmIrregular_MouseMove);
            this.cmsAllMenu.ResumeLayout(false);
            form.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon niMainMenu;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip cmsAllMenu;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem tsmiAbout;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem tsmiExit;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator tsmiSeparator;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrRotate;



    }
}
```

It's give error

Web Part Error: An error has occurred.

what is problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many reasons for this error.

```
using System.Linq;
```

is defenitely not supported in MOS 2007. Remove this line and test.

Also disable custom errors in web.config to display full error.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not causing your error, but unless you need to, it is recommended to have your web part inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart instead of Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.

For more details, see the Remarks section of [WebPart Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.aspx).